# ASP WCF Service Error does not contain a definition for x and no extension method x accepting a first argument of type x could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am trying to use a WCF Service within my ASP project with C#.  I am getting the error `'Final.Maintenance.MaintenanceClient' does not contain a definition for 'AddStudent' and no extension method 'AddStudent' accepting a first argument of type 'Final.Maintenance.MaintenanceClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`  I have added the service reference to the 'Final' directory but I am still getting this error.  Any ideas?

Maintenance.svc.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace MaintenanceService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class Maintenance : IMaintenance
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }

        public Boolean AddStudent(string firstName, string lastName, int courseID)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

IMaintenance.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace MaintenanceService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMaintenance
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
        [OperationContract]
        Boolean AddStudent(string firstName, string lastName, int courseID);
    }


    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

IMaintenance.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MaintenanceService.Maintenance" CodeBehind="Maintenance.svc.cs" %>
```

AddStudent.aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using(Maintenance.MaintenanceClient proxy = new Maintenance.MaintenanceClient()){
                if (proxy.AddStudent(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, Convert.ToInt32(DDCourses.SelectedValue)))
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Maintenance/StudentList.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "The student could not be added.";
                }
            }
        }
```

The error happens in AddStudent.aspx.cs on the line with if(proxy.AddStudent(...)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Where is `Final.Maintenance.MaintenanceClient` declared? Your proxy is of that type not `MaintenanceService.Maintenance`.

Comment: also try updating your service reference

Comment: @ChrisF So what exactly am I supposed to fix?

Comment: @Mysterio11 I have done that multiple times and it didn't help.

Comment: You need to look at your `MaintenanceClient` class and implement an `AddStudent` method that takes the arguments you want. It then needs to call the service.